# Is there a woot style site for Photo Equipment?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, selling

Besides [woot](http://www.woot.com), [Chain Love](http://www.chainlove.com), [Bonk Town](http://www.bonktown.com), anything for photo?

Comment: Lots of time/patience + Fredmiranda sales forum. But seriously, I am also very interested in this question. +1

Comment: You should probably explain what these sites are - I have never heard of any of them.

Comment: These are "deal" sites that post short time (usually a day or less) , limited supply offers are heavily discounted prices usually on either off brand, "last season", or refurb items that they buy in bulk.  I've some some Pentax stuff show up on Woot before.  The resale value on photography eq is high enough, it would surprise me to see much stuff hit these sites (and its rare that I have).

Comment: @JamWheel "Woot-style" usually means the site sells one item per day, or, more broadly, one item at a time. Woot.com was one of the first sites to do this, and they've stuck to it for a long time. A bunch of other sites have copied the model.

Comment: How could this be off topic, in order to have photography, or editing you must purchase equipment somewhere.  This is a legit question, otherwise it wouldn't have gotten so many upvotes...

Answer (score 1):

So, I'm pretty sure the answer is "no, there isn't".

Answer (score 0):

LensRentals.com [occasionally sells their old equipment for less than new prices](http://www.lensrentals.com/buy).  This is not at all the same as Woot or, ... wow, any of those other sites that I haven't heard of.  But it does mean you can get deals on used lenses or equipment in good condition.